# bundle install時にエラーが表示される

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/kojimadaiki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p645/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160104-7569-2gpugj.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/kojimadaiki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p645/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kojimadaiki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/kojimadaiki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.0.0/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

githubからフォークしたファイルをbundle installするとたまに上記のようなエラーが表示されます。

gem install pg -v '0.18.4'を打ってみてもエラーが続くのですが、どうしたらよいのでしょうか？

Comment: これだけだと情報が不足しています。スタックトレースを含めた全体のエラー情報と、使用しているOSのバージョンを追記してもらえると、回答が付くかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header" というキーワードで検索してみたところ、Postgres（libpq-dev）をインストールしたら直った、というような情報がいくつか見つかりました。

参考： [ruby on rails - Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem)

Postgresはインストールしていますか？もしまだなら先にPostgresをインストールしてから（Macなら `brew install postgresql` ）、pg gemをインストールしてみてください。